# App changed deactivated state programmatically in WP8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have developed window phone 8 application, After moved second-page When I clicked back-key button I want to app move to deactivated state and same time not moves to Main-page and close the app and then again we select that app means I need to start second page only.

Here I have tried so-far:

Mainpage.xaml:

```
<Button x:Name="start" Content="Go to secondpage" Height="150" 
    FontSize="37" Click="start_click"/>
```

Mainpage.xaml.cs:

```
private void start_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Secondpage.xaml",UriKind.Relative)); 
}
```

Secondpage.xaml.cs:

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    // what can I enter for minimize the app
}
```

I used `Application.Current.Terminate()` and `NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry()` but it was going to Application_closing state, so I select that app means it will select mainpage.

I need to go to Application_Deactivated state?

Comment: what do you mean by deactivating state? . You should remove back stack entry from 'OnBackKeyPress' of the second page

Comment: Yes I tried, but we select app again it will start from Mainpage, I need it goes to second page

Comment: you need to identify this scenario and navigate to your second page from onnavigatedTo event of the main page

Comment: I didn't understand ,How to Identfy and How to navigated

Comment: Please explain clearly, This is my first windows app development

Comment: Hello does anyone know this and please help me to solve this